# Secure Priv Option Mysql what is it?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Im trying to understand what does secure priv option mean? I tried looking on this forum but couldn't find anything.. could someone explain please?

i tried importing a csv file. its all done now, but need understanding what I have just done.

Comment: i assume you mean `--secure-file-priv` option or the variable `secure_file_priv` ?

Comment: both if you can explain

Comment: both have the same usage see [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_secure-file-priv)

Comment: Intresting.. why is that an option at all?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote in the MySQL [document](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_secure_file_priv)

> This variable is used to limit the effect of data import and export
>   operations, such as those performed by the `LOAD DATA` and `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` statements and the `LOAD_FILE()` function. These operations
>   are permitted only to users who have the FILE privilege.
>
> `secure_file_priv` may be set as follows:
>
> If empty, the variable has no effect.
>
> If set to the name of a directory, the server limits import and export
>   operations to work only with files in that directory. The directory
>   must exist; the server will not create it.
>
> If set to `NULL`, the server disables import and export operations. This
>   value is permitted as of MySQL 5.7.6.

Comment: if its turned on, does it cause any security issues?

Comment: Yes, because the user will have privileges to read any file on the server host that is readable by the world or readable by the MySQL server, it also allows the user to create new files in any directory where the MySQL server has write access. As a security measure, the server will not overwrite existing files.

Comment: To limit where files can be read and written, set the secure_file_priv system to a specific directory. [See Section 5.1.4, "Server System Variables"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html)

Comment: In the my.ini file you will find the field below and will add the path, as an example.
`[mysqld]
secure-file-priv = "/var/lib/mysql-files/"`